# Como puede mejorar este codigo, ya que lo veo obsoleto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo mejorar este codigo, lo que el hace es que toma una clase de enlaces (que trate de hacerlos amigables) de manera que a la persona se le haga facil crear un enlace, pero ese no es el problema, asi el funciona y crea un enlace amigable y una url un poco mas limpia. Soy nuevo en el sitio y de verdad disculpenme mi ignorancia al no saber, soy aun mas nuevo en programacion y he estado durante algun tiempo tratando de llevar un proyecto a cabo y he estado viendo que jquery simplifica muchas cosas y me gustaria aprender mas de el.

```
  $( ".linkbestia" ).each(function() {

  lnk = $(this).text();
  enlace= $(this).attr("href");
  espacios=lnk.replace(" ","_");
  maslimpio=espacios.replace("'","%27");
  muchomaslimpio=maslimpio.replace("(","%28");
  muchomuchomaslimpio=maslimpio.replace(")","%29");
  nuevoenlace=$(this).attr("href",enlace+muchomuchomaslimpio);

  });
```

Lo que tenia en mente era mejorarlo de forma que en vez de tener que ejecutar .replace varias veces, hacer algo asi como una expresion regular o arreglo que contenga todos los caracteres que quiero reemplazar, y he estado buscando soluciones, pero como todo esto se ejecuta de cierta manera por cada clase, me confundo siempre, de verdad espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a mejorar

Comment: ¿Y no será `encodeURI(lnk)` lo que tratas de hacer?

Comment: Disculpa, ya intenté eso, y lo hacia en la consola pero la url no lo hacia.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te dejo una función para hacerlo

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, "%2A");
}
```

Se usa la funcion estandar encodeURIComponent combinada con una expresión regular para reemplazar los caracteres que no estan contemplados y se aprovecha la funcion escape para reducir el código. Por lo que veo vos queres codificarlo de acuerdo al RFC3986 y por eso hay que reemplazar el asterisco también(que no es codificado por la función escape así que hay que agregar otro replace), si este no fuese el caso y solo querés reemplazar los caracteres que mostras en tu código elimina el último replace.

Acá podes encontrar mas info
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent

[EDICION]
Respondiendo a tu comentario te agrego como sería para que te reemplace tal cual lo haces vos. De todas maneras no entiendo bien que es lo que querés hacer pero te pongo tu mismo código un poco simplificado.

```
$( ".linkbestia" ).each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace(/['()]/g, escape).replace(/ /g, '_');
    $(this).attr("href", text);
});
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo, exactamente eso era lo que queria ahora lo que estuve tratando de hacer fue añadirle los espacios en un .replace a eso y no pude, igual lo deje en la parte del codigo que lo itera, pero muchisimas gracias.

Comment: ahh, claro vos queres reemplazar los espacios por guiones bajos mientras que la función encodeURIComponent te los reemplaza por %20. Ahí te agrego como sería para que te quede tal cual como vos lo habías hecho pero mas simplificado

Comment: `$( ".linkmazmorra" ).each(function() {

   
            enlace=$(this).attr("href");
            var text = $(this).text();
            text = text.replace(/['()]/g, escape).replace(/ /g, '_');
            $(this).attr("href",enlace+text);
            
            });` El codigo final trate de dejarlo asi, estaba tratando de editar el formulario para mostrarte como estaba tratando de que quedara, la otra parte la habia hecho en php, la idea es que el usuario pueda añadir una url de manera un poco mas facil.